# Send an alert when memory and cpu on linux VPS

Tags: linux, smtp, vps, monitor

I have a private linux vps and want to monitor it by sending email when memory or process usage is high.

Is there any free service to send email ? (solution like Sendinblue are requiring profesionnel account)

Other method to monitor vps are welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [HetrixTools](https://hetrixtools.com/feature/server-monitor/) and was satisfied with it. They have [instructions](https://docs.hetrixtools.com/add-a-server-agent-monitor/) for you to install an [open source agent](https://github.com/hetrixtools/agent) on your VPS which then sends data to your HetrixTools dashboard.

You can then set up alerts based on different criteria (like RAM or CPU usage) and also "Contact Lists" which include different services (like email and Telegram messages).

Whenever one of your criteria is met, you will receive a notification.

**Disclaimer:** I've no affiliation with HetrixTools.